# Displaying information from a database cell

Tags: php, sql, database

Okay, so I'm trying to create an SQL that will run when the page loads, I ahve this, however it's not returning correctly, I need it so when returned, if cell "player_presenter" is empty then do nothing, and if it is full then display the information in it, however it's always displaying as "Full".

It is connected to the database and running properly, I think it's my if function, still learning haha.

```
   <?php

    include 'database.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM player_table WHERE id = 1");



    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 

    {
        if(!empty($row['player_presenter']))
            {echo 'Empty';}

        else
            {echo 'Full'; }
    } 




    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: you didn't loop over results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if(empty($row['player_presenter'])) {
            echo 'Empty';
        } else { 
            echo 'Full'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks haha, knew I was missing something obvious >.<

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the part where you get the row (or rows) from the result i.e.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    if(!empty($row['player_presenter']))
            echo 'Empty';
        else
           echo 'Full';
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` - The OP's using the MySQLi_ API here, not MySQL_.

Comment: You're welcome Barry. Best to fix that before some (*you know what*) goes and downvotes you.